# Asyncpg Connection refused to the postgres db

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have Fast api service with postgres and redis databases. I try to set up the second instance for each database for testing. Docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'


services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: "uvicorn app.main:app --reload --host '0.0.0.0'"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      - local
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
      - test_postgres
      - test_redis
      
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=ryan_gosling
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password123
      - POSTGRES_DB=quizz_app 
    networks:
      - local
  
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
    networks:
      - local

  test_postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=test_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=test123
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
    networks:
      - local
  
  test_redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6380:6379"
    networks:
      - local


networks:
  local:
  
volumes:
  postgres_data:
  redis_data:
```

Main databases work fine, but test databases don't. I suppose something is wrong with port mapping in test db services, but I can't figure out what.

Postgres link (works fine): "postgresql+asyncpg://ryan_gosling:password123@postgres:5432/quizz_app"
Test postgres link (Asyncpg ConnectionRefusedError): "postgresql+asyncpg://test_user:test123@test_postgres:5433/test_db"

Redis test service refuses the connection as well

Comment: have you checked if the test_db service are online? Whats the output from on terminal:
`netstat -tunelp | grep 5433`

Comment: The output is:
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5433            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          4036186    -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::5433                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          4035161    -
Seems like it's online

Comment: The test database is running on 5432.  It is mapped to 5433 on the docker host, but you aren't connecting from the docker host, you are connecting from within docker.

Comment: In addition, It looks like your `test_postgres` service is missing a volume for the db data (same for `test_redis`). Regarding the port mapping, @jjanes is correct, since you are using the service names to resolve the containers.

Comment: So what do I have to change to solve the problem?

Comment: Simply change the port in your connection string "postgresql+asyncpg://test_user:test123@test_postgres:**5432**/test_db"